# 'type' object is not subscriptable in PYTHON while trying to print list

Tags: python, list, input, split

I want my program to output strings not instantly. I want it to type one character every 0.2 seconds. I wrote this code and it's giving me 'type' object is not subscriptable. Any ideas?

```
import sys
import time

botString = " "
#splits sentences into words
botStringSplit = botString.split()
#splits words into characters
listOfBotStringChar = list[botStringSplit]


def botType(botString):
    for i in range(len(botStringSplit)):
        time.sleep(0.2)
        print(listOfBotStringChar[i])


userInput = input("type something")

if "hi" in userInput:
    botString = "Hello friend"
    botType(botString)
```

UPDATE:
zondo and Jacques Gaudin suggested that I should change

```
listOfBotStringChar = list[botStringSplit]
```

to

```
listOfBotStringChar = list(botStringSplit)
```

this removes the error (thanks) but it doesn't output anything. Do you guys know why?

Comment: Look at the line the error message is pointing to. Subscripting is when you do something like `l[i]`. Do you see where you've written a subscript where you might have meant something else?

Comment: You should be using `()`, not `[]`

Comment: Okay its telling me that line 6 or listOfBotStringChar = list[botStringSplit] is giving me the error.

Comment: See my answer below for full code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
botStringSplit = botString.split()
#splits words into characters
listOfBotStringChar = list[botStringSplit]
```

`.split()` already returns a list. So your code is having issues when you are trying to index into the `list` type here: `list[botStringSplit]`.

If you wanted to convert to a list, use parenthesis instead:
`list(some_iterable)` - but as mentioned above, this should not be necessary as it would be equivalent to: `botStringSplit = list(botString.split())`

This will do what you want (in python 3), if you are in python 2, switch the `input()` to `raw_input()`

```
import time

def botType(botString):
    for i in range(len(botString)):
        time.sleep(0.2)
        print(botString[i])

userInput = input("type something: ")
if "hi" in userInput:
    botString = "Hello friend"
    botType(botString)
```

Comment: I use python 3.5 but I guess I just have to change raw_input to input, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Your line `list[botStringSplit]` is trying to find the index `botStringSplit` of the `list` class. Try `list(botStringSplit)` instead. Or just `botStringSplit` as it is already a list.